# CSS font-size set for <body> tag is not reflected properly

Tags: css, font-size

In my CSS styles, I have a selector for the body tag to set the overall font-size to 1.5em. The first two words in the html section are styled with a class having the font-size set to 1.3em. The rest has no specification of font-size.

```css
       body {
         font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, georgia, serif;
         font-size:1.5em;
         line-height: 1.3em;
       }
       .pathlink {
         font-size: 1.3em;
       }
```

```html
    <p><span class="pathlink">Start Page</span>Copyright &copy; 2023</p>
```

I would expect the first two words to show smaller (1.3em) compared to the following text (1.5em). However, when rendered in a browser, the first two words appear cleary larger that the rest. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `em` as a unit.

EM is relative to the current font size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font). So, If the font size of body is 1.5em (it will be relative to the browser-defaults i.e 16px) pixels, then 150% will be 24 pixels (1.5 * 16), and 1.3em will be based on 24 px then -> e.g (1.3 * 24) 31.2px  This is why in your case the 1.3em font is bigger than the body´s 1.5em

see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php

Comment: John, thanks a lot for your clear response! Would you consider it good practice to set the font-size for the body, and the other font-sizes as percentage values? My 1.3em would convert to font-size: 87%;

Comment: youre welcome, i guess the most important best practice is to use a consistent base font size and probably not rely on the browsers defaults, common buzzwords are reset/normalize css to unify display between browsers, here is also an article specifically about the usuage and bestpractices using em/rem https://hackernoon.com/when-and-where-to-use-rem-and-em-units-in-web-design

Comment: @thomas based on your comment, you should be using the `rem` unit instead of `em`.